# Python module runs but shows "Syntax error while detecting tuple" in aptana

Tags: python, aptana

I am learning python and when I was running the below code

```
print("X",end='awesome')
```

The code runs but shows the following syntax error

```
"Syntax error while detecting tuple"
```

How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana is set to use syntax checking for Python 2.x, where `print` is a statement. It is recognizing this statement as if you were trying to print a tuple, which is what that would be in Python 2.x, and correctly pointing out that you can't have an `=` sign inside the tuple. But the code is written for Python 3.x, where `print` is a function call and this syntax is valid.

You need to set Aptana to use the Python 3 grammar. I found [this page](https://pythoncodesnippets.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/how-to-configure-aptana-studio-with-python3-interpreter/) that shows you how to set up Aptana to use a Python 3.x interpreter (which you probably already have, since the script runs) and syntax.

Comment: thanks for the info. Now I don't get any syntax error.